# Build Solution Problem

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, try-catch

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with C#.

When I use the **Start Debugging** tool *(F5)* everything seems to work fine. So I build the solution.

Now I close out of Visual Studio 2010 and go to the path where the 'application' is kept for the program. When I double click on the file it runs the program fine.  However, when I go to click the "save" button in the GUI it saves the files but is being caught by my try/catch block.

Why does this happen in the application when I double click it, but not when I am running Visual Studio 2010 to debug?

### **EDIT:**

```
try
{
    StreamWriter sw2 = new StreamWriter(saveFile2.FileName);
    List<string> universalLineList = new List<string>();
    string file = saveFile2.FileName;
    string[] splitFile = file.Split('\\');
    string[] savedName = splitfile[6].Split('.');
    int i = 1;

    sw2.WriteLine(savedName[0]);
    sw2.WriteLine("Created on: " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " at: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
    sw2.WriteLine();

    while (i < stepAndRepeatcounter)
    {
        sw2.WriteLine("Line: {0}", i);
        i++;
    }

    sw.WriteLine();

    foreach(var line in theUniversalList)
    {
        if (line.Name.ToUpper().Contains("FID"))
        {
            sw2.WriteLine("Fiducial: {0}, X: {1}, Y: {2}",
                          line.Name,
                          line.XPlacement,
                          line.YPlacement);
        }
    }

    sw2.WriteLine("Placements: ");

    foreach (var line in theUniversalList)
    {
        if (!line.Name.ToUpper().Contains("FID"))
        {
            sw2.WriteLine("Name: {0}, X: {1}, Y: {2}",
                          line.Name,
                          line.XPlacement,
                          line.YPlacement);
        }
    }

    int j = 0;
    sw2.WriteLine("Slots: ");
    foreach (var line in theUniversalList)
    {
        if (!line.Name.ToUpper().Contains("FID"))
        {
            sw2.WriteLine("Slot: {0}, P/D: {1}, P/N: {2}",
                          j,
                          line.PartDescription,
                          line.PartNumber);

            sw2.WriteLine("Slot: 22, P/D: Reject, P/N: {0}",
                          line.PartNumber);

            j++;
        }
    }

    sw2.Close();
}

catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Could not format and save Universal-1 Placements", "Universal-1 Save Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}
```

Comment: You should probably look at the exception being caught in order to figure that out. Give us what the exception is and someone will probably be able to figure it out quickly.

Comment: what is the exception being thrown?

Comment: I'm sure is some I/O permission, as in debug mode all is writable.

Comment: I am confused on why it works running Visual Studio, but when I build it, and move that built file onto a different computer (or even the same computer) it works except for that saving part..

Comment: look - don't use "catch(Exception)". At a minimum use "catch(Exception ex)" and give us the content of "ex.ToString()"

Comment: @Ckoenig: It says System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the following lines:

```
string file = saveFile2.FileName;
string[] splitFile = file.Split('\\');
string[] savedName = splitfile[6].Split('.');
```

I guess your path is not long enough for the 7th element, when you are running the file from the command line (maybe the path is then something like ".\xzy.txt"

To be 100% sure check the StackTrace of the exception too, to get the line with the error.

Comment: How can I get the last item - 1? so there is actually 8 splitFile parts but I want #7. So I guess .. if there was 15 parts to splitFile how can I get #14? or if there was 99 parts to splitFile, how can I get #98? would it be something like `splitFile[splitFile.Length - 1].Split('.');`?

Comment: yes exactly. Please write the saveName to the console to check. I see no other part in your programm-snippet that could throw such a exception and the line is risky as it is.

Comment: Just use `System.IO.Path.GetFileName()`